# AWS WebSocket disconnect route not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket

Very new to cloud development and AWS. Learning about web sockets. Read documentation and looked at a couple of tutorials online.

I implemented connect, disconnect, default and sendMessage lambdas/routes. Used https://www.websocket.org/echo.html to verify if my implementation works.

Connect works as expected ( I hope ). I see a new record created in Dynamo as well as I see connect Lambda log in CloudWatch.

However, when I try to call disconnect. Nothing happens. CloudWatch not showing any logs for my disconnect lambda. I don't see any errors anywhere.

When I try to call message. I get :

```
{"message": "Forbidden", "connectionId":"aCHv_fdlPHcBDkQ=", "requestId":"aCH67HkUHPcFhaQ="}
```

Tried the same with **wscat** via terminal, same result. I see that all my lambdas deployed successfully. Really lost here.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your code for review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. My serverless.yml had an extra space of indentation for the disconnect and message lambda definitions. No error. Deployed no problem...but never worked. I guess I'll pay attention to it next time...spent like 3 hours on it. Facepalm!